# Xcode 7.3.1 - ld: framework not found opencv2

Tags: ios, opencv, xcode7

I get compilation error when trying to build a project with OpenCV. I made sure that:
1. I added framework in Project -> Targets -> Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries
2. I added framework search path in Project -> Targets -> Build Settings -> Framework Search Paths - I added $(PROJECT_DIR) (recursive) and $(PROJECT_DIR)/Libraries/OpenCV (recursive)

Still getting the error. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this error ?

Answer (score 1):

It appears as if you haven't added the framework to your project folder. You might have only added to your Link Binary With Libraries build phases but that will not copy the framework to the project folder.

Copy the framework to your project folder followed by now you need to add it to your build phase in **Link Binary With Libraries** section.

Now the linker will be able to find OpenCV dependencies.

Comment: In project folder I have "Libraries" subfolder, that is where I put OpenCV framework. Then I add it to Link Binary With Libraries. It still doesn't work.

Comment: From where did you link the framework for Link Binary With Libraries build phase?

Comment: I created a folder called Frameworks inside the project folder. Works for me. Thank you very much.